# about java, String.replaceAll

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I've been trying to solve this problem, i did a research a little about the replaceAll method and it seems that it uses a regular expression. But i never heard of any regular expression that contains '.' character. This is the code i've been using:

```
System.out.println(parsed[1]);
myStatus = parsed[1].replaceAll("...", " ");
System.out.println("new: " + myStatus);
status.setText(myStatus);
```

Output result is:

old...string
new:

Comment: Yes, because it replaces any 3 characters with a space character

Comment: Oh.. So '.' character does have a special meaning then. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: BTW: Welcome to SO! if you have found a working solution, you may close this question by click on the check mark on the left side of the chosen answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the literal String `"..."` (three dots), either:

- use `replace("...", " ")`, which does **not** use regular expressions
- use `replaceAll("\\.{3}", " ")`, which is how you specify a literal dot in regex

Unless you *need* to use `replaceAll()` (because some implementation you are calling uses it), use `replace()`

#### Edited:

Thanks [Louis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869736/louis-wasserman) `\\.{3}` *is* simpler than `\\.\\.\\.` (doh!)

Comment: I suspect `\\.{3}` might be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

What your call is actually doing is replacing any group of 3 characters to a space. Thus, the string `"old...string"` would become 4 spaces. You would require to escape the dots or define a [character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) [quantifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html), as they are [predefined characters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html).

Something like

```
myStatus = parsed[1].replaceAll("[.]{3}", " ");
```

**Note** : You can test your regular expressions for Java [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html).

Comment: @Bohemian, I had `\\.` first, then I saw your answer :P anyway, edited for a "better" pattern, IMO